# How do you determine if a stripe event object with the type charge.succeeded is a reocurring subscription payment

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I am using a Stripe webhook to update a database table when a charge succeeds.  This update should only happen when the event is a subscription's reoccurring payment (not the initial one that happens when they signup for the plan).  Is there any attribute of the event object that would help me determine if it is a subscription payment and not the initial payment that occurs on signup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for the invoice.payment_succeeded web hook. This will fire anytime a payment is made. For one of my sites, I have a users table and a membership table. On the first payment, there is no entry in the membership table for the user when the charge is attempted so when I catch the invoice.payment_succeeded event, I check if that table is empty for the user and if so I know it's the first payment. Once the charge is complete, then I insert a row in the membership table for the user. On subsequent invoice.payment_succeeded web hooks, I will have a row in the membership table for the user and I can update the database now that it is for sure a reoccurring payment. I don't think there is a way to tell directly from the API events if a charge is happening for the first time or a reoccurring payment.

https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-events-can-i-see-when-a-subscription-is-renewed